# app path returns permissions denied laravel

Tags: laravel

I think this is supposed to be trivial. I have a somewhat domain driven design of my laravel app. All modules are in the app folder.

```
     app --/
         Auth --/
              Providers/
                  AppServiceProvider.php
              routes/
                  web.php
```

I am trying to load routes from my appserviceprovider inside my boot function and this is what i have

```
    public function boot()
    {
        // $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/../routes');
    }
```

i already ran chmod -R 0755 on the app folder but i am getting a permissions denied error whenever i try to create a controller or model or any file for that matter. I have also added the provider into the app config file. What do i need to do?